# What is the order in the adjective forms? -music/musical instrument vs. -biology/biology class

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

Is there any order in the way the adjectives form?

There's

> Music --> Music**al** instrument
>
> electricity --> electric**al** circuit
>
> logic --> logic**al** sentence

But

> Biology --> biology class
>
> Internet --> internet shopping

Comment: The adjective form of *biology* is actually **biological**.  But we don't use it with "class" because it's a *class about biology*, not a *class that is biological*.  Same with music - you say "music class", not "musical class".

Comment: @stangdon: It depends on the intended meaning. A *biology class* is a teaching course (or the students who attend such a course), but a *biological class* is a taxonomic division (some subgroup of living organisms identified on the basis of biological characteristics).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Ah, good point.  I should have thought of that.  So yes, there's a *biological class* but also a *biology class*; a *music class* but not (I don't think) a *musical class*.

Comment: @stangdon: I think a teacher could feasibly say he'd rather teach a *musical class* than a *cloth-eared class* if he's been asked to train them for the upcoming school concert.

Comment: ...not to mention that once we accept that [alaturca and alafranga are musical and cultural concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alafranga_and_alaturca), there's also [Either alaturka must be modernised or alaturka must be rejected as a musical class altogether.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rejected+as+a+musical+class%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers very interesting but now I'm also curious if there actually is a way to categorize how to make adjectives from nouns.  Yes, biology -> biological and chemistry -> chemical, but then art -> artistic and literature -> literary and engineering is already both an adjective and a noun.

Comment: We also have ***electronic** circuits*, and ***electrified** fences* (plus OED includes such terms as ***electriferous*** and ***electricized***). There will be some *partial* "rules", but often it's just meaningless accidents of history which usages appear / survive, and exactly what contexts they tend to be used in.

Comment: *Biology* and *internet* aren't adjectives.  In your examples, they're nouns used attributively.

Comment: Heh, after eight comments on the original post, I think @snailplane put it most succinctly.